# C# code disapeared from script task after saving with "There is a compilation error. Do you want to save anyway" message

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, script-task

I am using VS2015 for SSIS development. My package consists of a script task which is very complex (has a number of classes and tricky logic). I made some modification to a class (in the script task), saved the modification, and wanted to close "Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015" which is used for working with C# code in SSIS. I received a VS message that my code had a compilation error, and it gave me a choice of "saving" anyway\"not saving". Since I was running out of work time, I hit "Save" and thought I would deal with the issue later.
Now when I open my SSIS project->script task, I can see that all my classes have gone. There is only one auto generated "ScriptMain.cs" that can be found.

Is there a way I can restore all my work? I cannot believe all code can just disappear if you press "save file" when a compilation error.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the package deployed to SSISDB?  If it is then you can import the current project as a new project then move the package over to the project you're working on, or restore the project and make it your current one.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The work had not been fully finished so I did not deploy it to SQL Server DB.

Comment: I was doing a lot of Script Task work in VS2015 a few weeks back, and I remember the Script Task project showing up on the StartUp tab (or what ever it's called) as a recently opened project. I was able to click on those links and go straight into the VSTA dev environment with my script. Maybe you can get to a previously auto-saved copy of your code that way?

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. I have been able to find part of the classes in the bin directory and they point directly to the "AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\SSIS_ST120\VstaW6_dU9b9h0anZx49cdFr0g\" temporary folder. But it only contains part of what I need: about 4 classes out of 13. I do not know why it is that way...

Answer (score 1):

There are many thread in the Visual Studio developer community talking about a software bug found in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 and it is mentioned that is fixed in the latest releases. **I don't think you can try anything more than searching the Script Task project temp directory and the package `bin` folder if it contains an old version of the package.**

The issue was mentioned in the following links:

- [Developer community - SSIS Script Task losing code](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/199587/ssis-script-task-losing-code.html)
- [Developer community - Script task losing code](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/313426/script-task-losing-code.html)
- [MSDN - Script Tasks losing code for Visual Studio 2015](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/248e8efd-88e3-44e0-8368-add679310906/script-tasks-losing-code-for-visual-studio-2015?forum=ssdt)
- [Developer community - Script Task losing code in SSDT 15.8.0](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311940/script-task-losing-code-in-ssdt-1580.html)

All links mentioned that you have to [install the latest release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) in order to prevent the error from occurring next time.

Comment: Thank you, Hadi. I will definetly take a look.